# Did I even use state management - notifyListeners() does not do anything

Tags: flutter, state-management

I have a simple app that takes two text fields and shows them in another page.

This is the first class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Login(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        color: Colors.teal,
        home: App(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Then in the App class I have this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Login log = Provider.of<Login>(context);
.
.
.
.
// textfields that take email and password inputs
.
.
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text('Save', style: GoogleFonts.pacifico()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    log.saveUser(  // THIS METHOD
                        User(emailController.text, passwordController.text));
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ShowUser(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
```

So that button press will do two things:

1. save the User object in the Login class implemented with ChangeNotifier.

The Login class is as follows:

```
class Login with ChangeNotifier {



 User currentUser;

  void saveUser(User user) {
    currentUser = user;

    // notifyListeners();  THIS LINE
  }

  User getUser() {
    return currentUser;
  }
}
```

2. The button press will also navigate to a second page that has the following code:

   ```
   Login login = Provider.of<Login>(context);
   User _user = login.getUser();
   ```

Then I use the _user instance to show the email and password.

The code works and my inputs show up in the second page. The issue here is it works whether notifyListeners() is commented out or not.

Am I even applying state management here?
Why isn't the notifyListeners method required?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how provider model works is:

1. It **renders the design** of a particular widget **(in your case App() widget)** with the data that you have initially in the ChangeNotifer class **(in your case Login class)**.
2. **If there occurs a change in any value inside ChangeNotifier class and you know that this change will affect the design**, Eg- Lets say on a button press u increment a counter variable which u are showing in the widget. So you know if value of  counter variable changes, the design has to update. If this is the case i.e design needs to be updated with the value, **than you call notifyListeners() and it'll update the design corresponding to the new values.**
3. **If you know that the change wont affect your design you dont need to call notifyListeneres()** which in your case is true because you set the current user and immediately push to a new screen so updating the design of previous screen doesnt make any sense and even if you do call notifyListeners() it wont matter because by then u'll already be on the new screen.

So that is what is happening in your case the **notifyListeners()** line that you have commented will not do anything noticable and is kind of useless there.

**BUT IT DOES NOT MEAN THAT YOU ARE NOT USING STATE MANAGEMENT, YOU ARE USING IT JUST NOT UPDATING THE DESIGN AFTER THE CHANGES IN DATA**

Comment: I think I understood your answer. So the change in my data happens before the update of the UI(pushing to a new page). So the new page just grabs the new data in the Login class. Therefore, there's no need for notifyListeners. If that's correct, what if I'm showing the user input in the same first page? notifyListeners is needed then, right?

Comment: yes if u login the user and rather than pushing the user to the new screen show the user details on the same screen than you needed to call notifyListeners() . but let me point out one thing that you are confusing urself with. 
Do not think of pushing to a new page same as an update of the UI(i.e a ShowUser() widget that is completely seperate from you App() widget). 
They are completely seperate things. 
Updating UI means ur navigator is not taking u anywhere else. 
while pushing to a new screen means that you have changed the Widget completely and new Login class object is created.